# Declare variable outside promise then, initialized inside promise then and access outside promise then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I need to access `outState` var which declared outSide class and then has set inside `getData()` func within promise `then()` func.

inside usrs func when loop has finished I need to access that but I cant.

```
let outState = {};
class A extends Component{
  getData(usr){
    db.collection('a/'+usr+'/bb').get().then(snap=>{
      for(i = snap.docs.length-1; i>=0; i--){
         outState[usr] = [...outState[usr], snap.docs[i].data()];
      }
    });
  }

  usrs(usrs){
    for(i = usrs.length-1; i>=0; i--){

       this.getData(usrs[i]);
       if(i===0){
        this.setState({ ...this.state, ...outState });
       }

    }
  }
}
```

I need to update state outside for loop, otherwise I can set the state inside promise func but It makes slow my app.
Just I want to access it outside promise then function and then outside of loop update it.

Comment: Why does it need to be outside the class? This seems like it might cause problems later

Comment: because there is more than 100 users if set the state inside promise function it will update the state within loop more than 100 time and this make the app slow on the time is executing getData function

Comment: Sounds like you're solving the wrong problem. Merge your state updates into one bulk update and do it once.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend refactoring your component to something approximately like this, to keep everything a bit cleaner:

```
class A extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      usersData: {}      
    }  
  }

  getData(usr){
      let dataForUser = {};
      db.collection('a/'+usr+'/bb').get().then(snap=>{
        for(i = snap.docs.length-1; i>=0; i--){
           dataForUser[usr] = [...dataForUser[usr], snap.docs[i].data()];
        }
      });
      return dataForUser;
    }

    usrs(usrs){
      let data = {};
      for(i = usrs.length-1; i>=0; i--){
         let userData = getData(usrs[i]);

         if(i===0){
          data = {...data, ...userData};
         }
      }
      this.setState({usersData: data});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this return just an emty object {}

Comment: Problem is when we initialize the dataForUser inside promise then(), and we can not access it with the updated value outside of promise then() function